# Keyboard shortcuts in char run mode (ansi-term) in Emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, keyboard

I use **WindMove** in Emacs **24.1** to move around multiple windows using keyboard shortcuts:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)          ; move to window on the left
(global-set-key (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right)         ; move "       "    the right
(global-set-key (kbd "M-I") 'windmove-up)            ; move "       "    above
(global-set-key (kbd "M-K") 'windmove-down);         ; move "       "    below
```

Is there a way to associate these **WindMove** keyboard shortcuts with **char run mode** on an **ansi-term**?  I would like to avoid having to switch into **line run mode** for moving between windows. After a while it becomes tedious to type <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> and <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> back and forth to go into/leave the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will work for you. It uses the Emacs advising mechanism, which allows a user to dynamically change a function's behavior without modifying its source code directly. In this case, it is used to make the `winmove-*` functions run `term-char-mode` before executing their original definition. If you are also using other window-selecting functions, such as `other-window`, besides `winmove-*`, you can advise those functions in the same way. Refer to [Advising Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) for details on the advising mechanism.

The code also handles the issue related to the `term-raw-map` keymap. `term-raw-map` is not defined until `term.el` is fully loaded (or <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>ansi-term</kbd> is executed). So you should add the `(define-key term-raw-map ...)` forms to the `term-load-hook` hook, which is automatically run when `term.el` is loaded, instead of putting them at the top level of the init file.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-I") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-K") 'windmove-down)

(defun ansi-term-char-mode ()
  (if (string= (buffer-name) "*ansi-term*")
    (term-char-mode)))

(defadvice windmove-left (before windmove-left-ansi-term (&optional arg))
  (ansi-term-char-mode))

(defadvice windmove-right (before windmove-right-ansi-term (&optional arg))
  (ansi-term-char-mode))

(defadvice windmove-up (before windmove-up-ansi-term (&optional arg))
  (ansi-term-char-mode))

(defadvice windmove-down (before windmove-down-ansi-term (&optional arg))
  (ansi-term-char-mode))

(add-hook 'term-load-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)
    (ad-activate 'windmove-left)
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right)
    (ad-activate 'windmove-right)
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-I") 'windmove-up)
    (ad-activate 'windmove-up)
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-K") 'windmove-down)
    (ad-activate 'windmove-down)))
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `term-char-mode` forwards most keys to the terminal, without interpreting them within Emacs, which is why `windmove` keybindings are not working.

Here is a way to override the `term-char-mode` keymap to force `windmove` bindings to be interpreted instead of forwarded:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(progn
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right)
     ;; ...
     ))
```

Comment: You are right, I was referring to term-char-mode, not term-line mode. I updated the OP. However your solution gives me an error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: term-raw-map`

Comment: Maybe you evaluated the expression before `term` was loaded. Try putting this in your init file: you could try the edited version of my answer, which ensures the key rebinding isn't evaluated too early

Comment: Otherwise, it could be a mismatch between our Emacs versions. I'm using `23.2.1`  (`C-h v emacs-version RET`)